# Use Find to list files and include counter value in output

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, macos

For performance reasons, I want to use `find` to list a large number of files, but also include a counter on each line. The following is what I have so far:

```
local root_dir="."
local ouptut_file="/tmp/foo.txt"

File_Number=99              ## Initial value

echo "" > "${ouptut_file}"  ## Initialize file to empty

find "$root_dir"   \
    -type f        \
    -depth 2       \
    -name '*.xxx'  \
    -print0        \
| sort -z          \
| xargs -0  printf "DoSomething %5d '%s'\n" $[File_Number++] -- \
> "${ouptut_file}"
```

This outputs

```
DoSomething    99 '--'
DoSomething     0 'dirA/dirB/file1.xxx'
DoSomething     0 'dirA/dirB/file2.xxx'
DoSomething     0 'dirA/dirB/file3.xxx'
```

what I want is

```
DoSomething     100 'dirA/dirB/file1.xxx'
DoSomething     101 'dirA/dirB/file2.xxx'
DoSomething     102 'dirA/dirB/file3.xxx'
```

How do I include the counter and also eliminate the first spurious line in the output.

*System*: Am using `bash` on macOS Ventura 13.0.1

Comment: You never need to initialize a file. You can just do `find ... > file` and the file will be created if it doesn't exist and will be emptied and its contents replaced with the output of the command if it did exist.

Comment: ... or if the `noclobber` option is set (with `set -o noclobber`in `~/.bashrc`), use `find ... >| file` which will clobber any already existing file upon redirecting output to them, something practical but unsafe by design ...

Comment: The easiest way to number lines is to use the `nl` command like that `find ... | nl --starting-line-number=100`. It doesn't support zero terminated strings and also has no way of prepending output lines with custom text.

Answer (score 5):

A couple of notes:

1. `$[...]` is a really old form of arithmetic expansion. These days the bash documentation doesn't even mention it. Use `$((...))` instead.
2. `xargs` will start a new process for each invocation of the command, so any changes to variables in one won't affect other invocations.
3. For `printf(1)`, `--` is just like any another argument. What's happening is that `xargs` runs `printf "DoSomething %5d '%s'\n" $[File_Number++] dirA/dirB/file1.xxx dirA/dirB/file2.xxx ...`, and `printf` loops over the arguments to fit the format string requirements. So every alternate filename is actually being treated as a number, resulting in the `0` in the output.

You might want to use something like:

```
find "$root_dir"   \
    -type f        \
    -depth 2       \
    -name '*.xxx'  \
    -print0        \
| sort -z          \
| while read -r -d '' file; do
     printf "DoSomething %5d '%s'\n" $((File_Number++)) "$file"
  done > "${ouptut_file}"
```

Also note that if you're actually using this to print commands for running in a shell, you should use `%q` instead of `'%s'` for proper quoting. From `help printf`:

> In addition to the standard printf(1) formats, %b means to
> expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument, and %q
> means to quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input.

Comment: Using `printf %q` is not the safest if it's to be interpreted by a Bourne-like shell. As the OP's on macos, they have the option to use [`zsh` which has more reliable quoting operators](/a/600214).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas is right about the safety of `printf %q`, but if you can always know the conditions of your file system and can be assured that you'll never be sending it anything risky, that would mitigate the risk.

Comment: Point 2 isn't relevant here, because the variable here is expanded by the shell before `xargs` sees anything.  So there's only ever one increment of `$File_number` regardless of how many processes are started there.  Otherwise, a great explanation of _why_ the script doesn't do what Peter was expecting.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `perl`:

```
find "$root_dir"   \
    -type f        \
    -depth 2       \
    -name '*.xxx'  \
    -print0        \
| sort -z          \
| perl -l -0ne 'printf "something %05d %s\n", $., $_' > "$output_file"
```

If you need to quote the files, putting `'` on either side may not be enough depending on what file names may contain and what language those quotes are intended for. For instance, in several languages including some shells, the `\` and newline characters are still special within quotes and would need to be escaped. In any case, the `'` character cannot be embedded asis in a single quoted string.

If the quoting is for a Bourne-like shell, you can do quoting with a:

```
sub shquote {return "'" . ($_[0] =~ s/'/'\\''/gr).  "'"}
```

function which [is the safest form of quoting in those shells](/a/600214)¹. So here:

```
perl -l -0ne '
  sub shquote {return "'\''" . ($_[0] =~ '"s/'/'\\\\''/gr"').  "'\''"}
  printf "something %05d %s\n", $., shquote($_)'
```

Or if you struggle to keep track of all those quotes:

```
perl -l -0nse '
  sub shquote {return $q . ($_[0] =~ s/$q/$q\\$q$q/gr) . $q}
  printf "something %05d %s\n", $., shquote($_)' -- -q="'"
```

Also note that outputting to files with fixed name in world writable areas is bad practice from a security standpoint. Someone could create a symlink with the same name to some sensitive file you have write access to for instance. Creating files in /tmp should only be done with randomly generated file names and with `O_NOFOLLOW` like `mktemp` does, or in freshly made private directories there (bailing out if it can't be created, like for instance if it already existed).

---

<sup>¹ Safer than the `String::ShellQuote` CPAN module in any case which has a [few](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=118508) [issues](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=118507).</sup>

Comment: I am getting `No such file or directory` on the line with the `perl` statement. I am using the `bash` shell that comes with Mac so that is probably the issue.